# How to remove everything from ListView using a button onClick?

Tags: java, android

How to remove everything from ListView using a button onClick? When i try "fullCourseList.clear();", I can't add any more courses and the page is refreshed only after visiting the page again

```
import static com.example.diplom.MainActivity.fullCourseList;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.diplom.model.Course;
import com.example.diplom.model.Order;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OrderPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_page);

        ListView orders_list = findViewById(R.id.orders_list);

        List<String> coursesTitle = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Course c : MainActivity.fullCourseList) {
            if(Order.items_id.contains(c.getId()))
                coursesTitle.add(c.getTitle());

        }

        orders_list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, coursesTitle));


    }

    public void openMain(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //fullCourseList.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: try `orders_list.setAdapter(null);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should save off the adapter so you can call `clear()` on it. Clearing the list this way will also automatically notify the adapter to update. Since you copied your data into a new list (`coursesTitle`) clearing the original list will have no immediate effect.

For example:

```java
public class OrderPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private ListView orders_list;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_page);
        orders_list = findViewById(R.id.orders_list);
        List<String> coursesTitle = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Course c : MainActivity.fullCourseList) {
            if(Order.items_id.contains(c.getId()))
                coursesTitle.add(c.getTitle());
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, coursesTitle)
        orders_list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        adapter.clear();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you *also* want to clear the currently displayed course items out of the master list, you would need to add code like this as well. If that isn't want you want, you need to be more clear in your question about the desired behavior.

```java
public void onClick(View v) {
    // clear what is currently shown in the list
    adapter.clear();

    // Clear the currently displayed entries out of the master list.
    // You may also be able to use "removeIf" if you have a new
    // enough java/api version
    Iterator<Course> itr = MainActivity.fullCourseList.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        Course c = itr.next();
        if(Order.items_id.contains(c.getId())) {
            itr.remove();
        }
    }

    // And if you want to ENTIRELY clear the master list, you
    // could just do this instead
    // MainActivity.fullCourseList.clear()
}
```

Comment: It's worked, but when i again open my list, the data appears there again, but I did not add it

Comment: Yes... That is because the data is still also in `fullCourseList`

Comment: I added an edit to the answer. You must understand that the data shown in the list is a copy (of just the titles) made from the original source data in `fullCourseList`. Clearing the adapter will clear what is shown but will have no effect on the source list, and clearing the source list will have no affect on the adapter. If you want them both cleared, you need to edit both (as I show in the answer now)

Answer (score 0):

After clearing the ArrayList you have to notify the adapter that the data source has been changed.

```
public class OrderPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private ListView orders_list;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_page);
        orders_list = findViewById(R.id.orders_list);
        List<String> coursesTitle = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Course c : MainActivity.fullCourseList) {
            if(Order.items_id.contains(c.getId()))
                coursesTitle.add(c.getTitle());
        }
        orders_list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, coursesTitle));
    }

    public void openMain(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        fullCourseList.clear();
        orders_list.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: Gives an error message to "orders_list"

Comment: @Slader because you've declared it inside your onCreate

Comment: error "Cannot resolve method 'notifyDataSetChanged' in 'ListView'"

Answer (score 0):

Everything was easier than I thought, I confused myself with my own class names. Thank you all very much for your help!
This worked:

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.diplom.model.Course;
import com.example.diplom.model.Order;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.List;

public class OrderPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView orders_list;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_page);
        orders_list = findViewById(R.id.orders_list);
        List<String> coursesTitle = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Course c : MainActivity.fullCourseList) {
            if(Order.items_id.contains(c.getId()))
                coursesTitle.add(c.getTitle());
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, coursesTitle);
        orders_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        adapter.clear();
        Order.items_id.clear();
    }
    public void openMain(View view){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```